# Inexplicable IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, richtextbox, indexoutofboundsexception

I've got a rich text box with multiple lines of text in it, and upon 'clicking' on a portion of the text, I'd like to extrapolate the line of text that has been clicked on, and write it out to another window for more processing - The issue I'm having is that in some circumstances the following code is throwing an IndexOutOfRangeException, which I would assess as impossible from my meager viewpoint... I would assume that there would be interopability between GetLineFromCharIndex() and RichTextBox.Lines; especially when using other 'inclusive' variables like the 'SelectionStart'.

In at least one circumstance, clicking on my 'last line' of text when there is an empty line following it ( making it not actually the last line... ) throws an exception.

```
    void OutputField_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!this.LineEditor.Visible)
                this.LineEditor.Show();

            if (this.OutputField.SelectionStart == this.OutputField.TextLength)
                return;

            int TargetLine = this.OutputField.GetLineFromCharIndex(this.OutputField.SelectionStart);
            String LineText = this.OutputField.Lines[TargetLine];

            this.LineEditor.SetContent(TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.Zero, LineText);

            return;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

Specifically; the line that I am finding exceptions on is the following;

```
String LineText = this.OutputField.Lines[TargetLine];
```

Any hints tips or suggestions would be much appreciated. Thanks folks.

Comment: Do you have the length of `Lines` and the value of `TargetLine` which causes the problem?

Comment: I've checked a couple of times Penguin, and when the exception is being thrown the two numbers are clearly out of 'balance' as it were, but I'm not sure how that can be the case - which I suppose is more the question...

Comment: In most cases I've noted that the TargetLine is one higher than the count of Lines; when the exception is encountered.

Comment: It would only seem logical to me; that the code behind both of these operations is based on the same logic - at least in the sense of determining how many lines are in the text...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `GetLineFromCharIndex()` returns the actual line displayed on the screen, not necessarily the index from `Lines[]` if `WordWrap` is on.  Give it a go with `WordWrap` off and see if it works as expected.

[Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.getlinefromcharindex.aspx)

Comment: Awesome. I wasn't aware that WordWrap had any bearing on the situation - Ill give it a spin. Thank you.

Comment: No worries, glad I could help. At least the first few downvotes got you some rep from compensation upvotes - downvotes are -2 but upvotes are +10

Comment: Haha well what goes around comes around I suppose - I'll have to remember to title my posts better in the future. Thanks again, that seemed to be the resolution.